# Improve location using Bluetooth?

Tags: location, classification, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

For my project i need estimate the point on a grid that i use. To check my method works i took some Readings through x axis as below when y=2;[image]

Blue, Brown and Grey are the access point 1,2 and 3 average RSSI readings. The node moves from red dot to blue which is 120 cm.The fluctuations of the RSSI readings are not linear and this is a very big problem in my case to get the accurate position. I use Knn to get the nearest position. What can i do to make it correct.? Use some other classifier will help ?

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you will get that level of precision from a BLE device signal. The orientation of the device and the movement of people in the space

Comment: The orientation was same for all the measurements and it is an empty space.

Comment: What is the size of the room you're testing in. How many RSSI-values are you sampling over time ?.

Comment: Is that the same (hardware) technology that iBeacons use?

Comment: Osman- I use the grid of 7.2x8.4 m^2. 42 reference points. i take maximum 100 reading from a point.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Is rssi a reliable parameter in sensor localization algorithms: An experimental study](http://www.cse.buffalo.edu/srds2009/F2DA/f2da09_RSSI_Parameswaran.pdf)

While i dont completely agree to the way those tests were executed and analyzed, they miss alot of details on analyzing the results such as differentiating the readings of RSSI over the different BLE channels, or measurements on antenna characteristics and orientation, the core statement i consider quite on point.

*RSSI cannot be used as a reliable metric in localization algorithms*

Beside the issues reflection, shadowing, antenna characteristics, etc. pose on the difficulty, the BLE Specification itself adds to the problem as the RSSI is not defined as an absolute value, it is specified to be used in a *relative* manner related to the distance to the *golden receiver range*, the rx power that would be not too weak and not too strong for the receiver to have the best receive quality. Also this RSSI can vary +/- 6dBm from the real value.

This means, we can hardly rely on the same readings across different devices and secondly, the accurracy is allowed to vary alot according to the specification.

For that reason, projects relying too hard on that accurracy are doomed to fail one way or another. However there are still applications possible getting something positive out of these RSSI readings, i.e. not relying completely on them, but instead use them as *indicator* in a supportive way.

If you are interested more on this matters, search for *Indoor localization rssi* i.e. on google scholar.